# Seeking Advice on Resistor Package Selection for Voltage Sensing in BLDC Motor Controller

Tags: resistors, circuit-design, pcb-design, power-electronics, motor-controller

In a BLDC motor controller's voltage sensing circuit, I've seen larger resistors (1206/0805) used at the battery's positive terminal. I'm considering a 0402 package resistor for this spot. Are there concerns with power dissipation, voltage rating, or reliability in using a 0402 in this high-power context?

Thanks for any insights!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjRfhV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: 0402 resistors can handle up to 50V and 0.062W. so in your case the power dissipated over R1 and R2 is 55.862mW which is very close to the limit. increase the values and you'll be OK.

Comment: Thank you! @ElectronSurf, I will try changing the values.